# Rails: why emails are sent before Users submit the form?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, email, controller, routes

I have a "Static form" that sends pricelists to clients, I need to send an email but params[:pricelist_name] from the form is nil.

I noticed that emails are sent before the view, so I was wondering how to send emails only after that users submit the form ?

Cheers,

**Controller**

```
  def sendpricelist
    @pricelist = params[:pricelist_name] || []
    @request_id = params["pricelist_name"] || []
    @test = "test"
    SaasMailer.pricelist_request_email(@pricelist, @test, @request_id).deliver_now
    #redirect_to :requests
end
```

**View**

```
    <%= form_tag(:controller => "requests", :action => "sendpricelist") do %>
  <%= text_field(:post, :title, size: 69, class: 'form-control form-group-lg') %>


<%= select_tag 'pricelist_name', 
  options_from_collection_for_select(Pricelist.all, :id, :name) %>


    <%= submit_tag("Send pricelist")%>



<% end %>
```

**Routes**

```
 devise_for :users
 resources :users
 resources :requests do
 resources :updates
match '/sendpricelist',      to: 'requests#sendpricelist',           via: 'get'

end
```

**Output:**

As you can see in 'Subject: [] - [] - test' params are nil.

```
Started GET "/requests/12/sendpricelist" for 127.0.0.1 at 2016-12-04 15:20:45 +0000
Processing by RequestsController#sendpricelist as HTML
  Parameters: {"request_id"=>"12"}
  Rendered saas_mailer/pricelist_request_email.html.erb within layouts/mailer (0.2ms)

SaasMailer#pricelist_request_email: processed outbound mail in 19.6ms

Sent mail to remyukjob@gmail.com (2012.5ms)
Date: Sun, 04 Dec 2016 15:20:45 +0000
From: from@example.com
Reply-To: remyukjob@gmail.com
To: remyukjob@gmail.com
Message-ID: <5844344d7cc60_23a33f8f3527db9467454@remy-Aspire-ES1-512.mail>
Subject: [] - [] - test
Mime-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/html;
 charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable

<html>
  <body>
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta content=3D'text/html; charset=3DUTF-8' http-equiv=3D'Content-Ty=
pe' />
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1><img src=3D"https://ci4.googleusercontent.com/proxy/HzK8rp8AJ2iFz=
l3q5Z2jtTKO4tCzMTfOJ9WT7CAzSVpHdXm676yMNYhbZzgrNSjFyzkChWQRdKCSZe7M-xrt6q=
IRl5wXoecqdqR3gUOINxF9CnwQoFC2YGQyG7FhdTAcWS9FNwRTDDh2KOkvTGxOOXOc=3Ds0-d=
-e1-ft#http://www.sweetconcepts.com/wp-content/themes/twentysixteen-child=
/assets/images/sc_logo.jpg" alt=3D"Sc logo" /></h1>
    <p>
      Bonjour Sandrine,
    </p>

     <p>
      Merci pour votre demande  nil.
      <br></br>
      J=E2=80=99ai joint en pi=C3=A8ce jointe les pricelists pour :
    </p>

      Pricelisttitle <a href=3D"https://s3.amazonaws.com/promosweetsdocs/=
Confirmation.pdf">Lien</a> =



  </body>
</html>
  </body>
</html>

  Pricelist Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "pricelists".* FROM "pricelists"
  Rendered requests/sendpricelist.html.erb within layouts/application (18.6ms)
Completed 200 OK in 2228ms (Views: 134.3ms | ActiveRecord: 2.8ms)


Started POST "/requests/12/sendpricelist" for 127.0.0.1 at 2016-12-04 15:20:51 +0000
```

Comment: try this in your view: `<%= form_tag sendpricelist_path do %>` ([source](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25984464/rails-4-form-tag-usage))

Comment: @NoamHacker Emails are still sent before I submit the form. cheers.

Comment: ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/requests/12/sendpricelist"):

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed my route to `match '/sendpricelist',      to: 'requests#sendpricelist', :`via => [:get, :post]`